# Select all Items which don't have a particular value in another table

Tags: t-sql

```
Table: Car
Columns: CarID, Value

Table: Tyres
Columns: TyreID, CarID, Brand
```

How can I select all `Cars` which don't have a corresponding `Tyre` which is of a certain `Brand`. In this scenario a car could have a number of different tyres each of which has a different brand.

E.g.

Car1 has 4 tyres, 2 x Brand A, 1 x Brand B, 1 x Brand C. 
Car2 has 3 tyres, 1 x Brand A, 2 x Brand B. 
Car3 has 4 tyres, 3 x Brand A, 1 x Brand C.

I want to find out the CarID of all vehicles which don't have a single tyre of Brand C. In this instance the result would be Car2.

Example Data:

```
Car
CarID   Value
--------------
1       Abc
2       Def
3       Geh

Tyre
TyreID  CarID   Brand
----------------
1       1   Brand A
2       1   Brand A
3       1   Brand B
4       1   Brand C
5       2   Brand A
6       2   Brand B
7       2   Brand B
8       3   Brand A
9       3   Brand A
10      3   Brand A
11      3   Brand C

Result
ID      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NOT EXISTS instead NOT IN because IN clause have a limit of 2500 rows

```
SELECT CarID 
FROM Car
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 'X'
  FROM Tyres
  WHERE Brand='Brand C'
  and Tyres.carId = Car.carId
)
```

Comment: Yes, `NOT EXISTS` is usually more efficient way, but 2500 row limit is just a legend, I think.

Comment: Hi, is real 2.500! some days ago I wrote a query where subquery returned a lot of results (>2500) and... BOOOOOM! P.S. In Oracle is 1.000.

Comment: @Joe If the car has 3 x Brand A, and 1 x Brand C. It still returns the CarID for the 3 x Brand A tyres which the car has. I don't want to return a single result if that car has 1 or more tyres which are Brand C. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: @Jack: Sorry but with posted query you show only Car2. Car1 and 3 not match the NOT EXISTS condition. Peraphs I don't understand you example. Please edit your comment with other examples so I can help you.

Comment: @Joe i've updated my question to include some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @Jack: Your example tells query written in my solution is OK. If you have a car with 2 tyres with Brand C, this must be treated as car1 and car3 or as car2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` clause

```
SELECT CarID 
FROM Car
WHERE CarID NOT IN (
  SELECT CarID 
  FROM Tyres
  WHERE Brand='Brand C'
)
```